# Convert Blazor WASM Project to A Progress Web App

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

With recent updates to .NET 5 / ASP.net Core, Microsoft has added support for creating a hosted Blazor WASM project as a [Progressive Web App](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps).

I have an already *established* project in which I would like to transition to being a Progressive Web App.

I've searched around on Microsoft's documentation for what this "conversion" looks like but haven't been able to find it.

Does anyone have a solution for *how* to modify an existing Blazor WASM project to function as a PWA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created two solutions same name different folders. 1st non PWA 2nd PWA both self hosted. I committed the non PWA to git. Then copied the PWA over the top of the first. The image is basically the changes. Here is a link to the [commit](https://github.com/BrianLParker/PwaConvert/commit/545766e0ba34dd24723418a2525f779b711827e7)

[image]

Comment: Great answer--thanks! I was thinking about taking this same approach if I didn't hear from anyone today. Really appreciate the insight/action here.